# Finding the Width at the Bottom of a Vertical Parabolic Arc

Tags: analytic-geometry

For a National Board Exam Review:

> An arc 18m high has the form of a parabola with the axis vertical. If
>   the width of the arc 8m from the top is 64m, Find the width of the arc
>   at the bottom.

Answer is 96

Construct Equation:

$${ (y-k) = -4a(x-h)^2 }$$

Assume ${(h,k) = (0,18) }$ and ${(x,y) = (64/2,10)}$

$${ (10-18) = -4a(32)^2 ; a = \frac{-1}{152} }$$

$${ a = \frac{1}{152} }$$

${ Change (x,y) to (x,0) }$$

$${ (0-18) = -4(\frac{1}{152})(x-0)^2 ; x=26.15 ... }$$

What am I doing wrong? Any Hint?

Comment: where you wrote 18-10 should be 10-18

Comment: @Chester edited!

Comment: ... which would only swap a sign, but your $a$ is incorrect as well. FYI: it is quicker to do the arithmetic for this problem if you write things in powers of 2, i.e. $8=2^3$, $4=2^2$, $32 = 2^5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w > 0$ be the desired width. Place the origin at the vertex so that the parabola has the form $y = ax^2$. Then the parabola goes through the points $(32, -8)$ and $(w/2, -18)$. Plugging in the first point yields:
$$
-8 = a(32)^2 \iff a = \frac{-1}{4 \cdot 32}
$$
Plugging in the second point yields:
$$
-18 = \frac{-1}{4 \cdot 32} \cdot \frac{w^2}{4}
\iff w^2 = (4 \cdot 4)(2 \cdot 9)(2 \cdot 16) \iff w = 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 96
$$

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $a=1$, your horizontal movement when you are $8$ metres below the arc's maximum should be its square root, $2 \sqrt2$. However, the width of one half the arc is $32$, meaning that the arc is $\frac {32} {2 \sqrt2} $, or $8 \sqrt2$ times wider than if $a=1$. Similarly, at $18$ metres below the arc's maximum, the width of one half the arc should be its square root, or $3 \sqrt2$. However, we know the arc is  $8 \sqrt2$ times wider than this, so we multiply the two.

$$8 \sqrt2 * 3 \sqrt2 = 24 * 2 = 48. $$

Remember, this width is only one half of the arc at its base. Thus,

$$48 * 2 = 96$$

Hope this helped.